# Visual Studio Code C# IntelliSense doesn't work after upgrade to v1.1.1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm using Visual Studio Code, as a code editor for Unity 5.

Visual Studio Code updated itself, after that I found that my C# IntelliSense seems to be broken. It doesn't show suggestions for my classes, it shows only c# syntax suggestions. I've checked all the settings, and logs so everything seems to be correct.  There is right workspace settings, OmniSharp is running an no errors in Log. I've tried uninstall/install VSCode but no luck. I can't understand what is the problem, and I need your help.

Any solutions? Screenshots are below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have to do with the C# Omnisharp plugin.

> Support for .csproj projects has been temporarily disabled on OS X and Linux. This will impact anyone doing .csproj development on OS X or Linux (e.g. Unity, Xamarin, etc.). Rest assured that this will be restored in the near future. However, for now, you can use the Legacy C# Support extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: Yes.. this is the core of my problem. I've updated not only Visual Studio Code itself, but all extensions with Omnisharp too. So replacing C# extension with Legacy C# Support extension did trick, and everything works just fine now. Thank you!